# CakePHP + nuSOAP - exposing a global function as a closure or using models outside of the controller?

Tags: cakephp, nusoap

I need to implement a SOAP service in a CakePHP controller. The exposed function names need to be in a global namespace (as in "Authenticate", not "SOAPController.Authenticate"). This forces me to implement Authenticate in the global namespace, since nuSOAP will deduce where to look for the function from its name. On the other hand, on the example below, I cannot use CakePHP's API, because I have no access to SOAPController's `this`. That is why I thought I should somehow declare some kind of a closure, that would resolve to 'Authenticate' in the global scope, while keeping a reference to `this` through bound parameter. Is that possible? Below is the erroneous code:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::import('Vendor', 'nusoap', 
        array('file' => 'nusoap'.DS.'lib'.DS.'nusoap.php')
);
/**
 * SOAP Controller
 *
 */


class SOAPController extends AppController {

        public function index()
        {
                $namespace = '';
                $server = new soap_server();
                $server->debug_flag = false;
                $server->configureWSDL("PAI2WSDL", $namespace,
                        "http://localhost/pai2/SOAP/?wsdl");
                $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;

                function Authenticate($login,$haslo){
                        $this->log("TEST"); //won't work!
                        return true;
                }

                $server->register('Authenticate',
                  array('ContractorId' => 'xsd:int', 'Password'=>'xsd:string'), 
                  array('return' => 'xsd:boolean'),
                  $namespace,
                 $namespace . '#Authenticate',
                  'rpc',
                  'encoded'
                );

                $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'])
                          ? $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';
                $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
                $this->autoRender = false;
                exit();
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about creating a `SoapComponent`?

Comment: Creating? If I had weeks to finish the project, it would make sense.

Comment: Creating a `Component` just takes minutes, and you will be able to use the components code in each `Controller`. See [Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component) for more information

Comment: How will the component programming help me solve the scope problem with nuSOAP?

Comment: The `SoapComponent` will allow you to use `Authenticate()` in each controller. And the initialization of a component will set the controller to `$this->controller` which will make it possible to use other CakePHP APIs